# Open a tab depending on the condition in TabActivity

Tags: android-tabactivity

I am creating an android application. I have a LoginActivity. After clicking on submit button in LoginActivity I want to call a TabActivity.  In that TabActivity I want to open tabs depending on the condition i.e. depending on the condition(which was set as a bundle in the intent while calling the TabActivity). Let us suppose I am sending some key-value pair with intent. depending on that value I want a particular tab to come in front when TabActivity starts.

Comment: TabActivity: This class was deprecated in API level 13.
New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT. 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: and set the default tab based on the condition e.g setDefaultTab(int index).